# Chart.js Convert JSON to PHP array

Tags: php, json, chart.js

I am creating a Time Cartesian Chart from Chart.js, I need to get the data as json format, however I need to first generate a php array and use json_encode() in order to get the following json. Does anyone knows what the php array be like inorder to get the following JSON?

```
            data: [{
                x: '2021-11-06',
                y: 50
            }, {
                x: '2021-11-07',
                y: 60
            }, {
                x: '2021-11-07',
                y: 20
        }]
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: If you `json_decode` your JSON string, that will show you what the PHP array has to look like...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
$data = [
          [
            'x' => '2021-11-06',
            'y'=> 50
          ],
          [
            'x' => '2022-11-07',
            'y'=> 60
          ],
          [
            'x' => '2023-11-07',
            'y'=> 20
          ]
         ];


$data = json_encode($data);
```

Comment: $k???  There is no $k.  Did you mean `
$data = json_encode($data);`?

Comment: sorry, yeah it's $data